# Problem with many-to-many relation : model is not found in app : "has not been installed"

Tags: django, django-models

that's my first post on stackoverflow.
Let me know if I can improve my post.

I tried to re-launch an old project. The architecture is composed of 2 apps:

- blog
- authentication

blog.models contains :

```
class BlogContributor(models.Model):
    contributor = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contribution = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ("contributor", "blog")
```

authentication.models :

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    CREATOR = "CREATOR"
    SUBSCRIBER = "SUBSCRIBER"

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (CREATOR, "Créateur"),
        (SUBSCRIBER, "Abonné"),
    )
    profile_photo = models.ImageField(verbose_name="photo de profil")
    role = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, verbose_name="rôle")

    follows = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        limit_choices_to={"role": CREATOR},
        symmetrical=False,
        verbose_name="suit",
    )
    blogs = models.ManyToManyField(
        "self",
        through="BlogContributor",
        related_name="contributors",
    )
```

An issue occurs :

```
authentication.User.blogs: (fields.E331)

Field specifies a many-to-many relation through model 'BlogContributor', which has not been installed.
```

I tried :

- to import BlogContributor in the file
- to import BlogContributor in authentication **init**.py

When I do the last action another issue occurs :

```
raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you haven't added your blog app to the INSTALLED_APPS under settings.py?

Answer (score 0):

There are a two errors in the definition of the `blogs` field in your `User` model. I believe you should replace it by :

```
blogs = models.ManyToManyField(
    Blog,
    through="blog.BlogContributor",
    related_name="contributors",
)
```

Use `"self"` when you need to create a many-to-many relation with the same models (for example wan can imagine a `followers` field on the `User` model)

And from the documentation :

> To refer to models defined in another application, you can explicitly
> specify a model with the full application label.

That's why I added `blog.` before `BlogContributor`